# How to get N consecutive digits from a string?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to get 4 consecutive digits from a string wherever it is matched.

when I am trying `re.sub('[^\d]+', ',', "abc 23 [1981] ghj [5656]")` it returns `,23,1981,5656,`.so when i do `re.sub('[\d]{4}+', ',', "abc 23 [2021]")` it returns an error `"multiple repeat at position 7"`

Since I am keeping `{4}`, shouldn't it match for 4 occurrences of `[\d]` and return `,1981,5656,` ?

Comment: `print(re.findall(r"\d{4,}", s))`?

Comment: @Rakesh this returns `['1981', '5656']` a list and then again i have to convert this to a string instead can't it be done using regex.sub so that it returns a string

Comment: `print(", ".join(re.findall(r"\[(\d{4})\]", s)))` ?

Comment: @ShivamRaj: You can't quantify a quantifier in Python which is why you're getting error due to this regex `[\d]{4}+`. Also you don't need to put `\d` in char set if `\d` is alone within it. Can you specify clearly your current output vs expected output?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: if there is no `+` i don't get any error instead it does returns something. on doing this `re.sub('[^\d]+', ',', "abc 23 [1981] ghj [5656]")` i am getting `,23,1981,5656,` but i want `,1981,5656,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a little tricky if you want to do it using regex only.

Instead you can use lambda to conditionally replace parts of string that is not four digits with a comma and retain the four digits as it is. Try using this Python code,

```
import re

s = "abc 23 [1981] ghj [5656]"
print(re.sub(r'\b(\d{4})\b|((?!\b\d{4}\b).)+', lambda x: x.group() if x.group(1) else ',', s))
```

Prints following just like you wanted,

```
,1981,5656,
```

What we are doing here is, capturing four digits using `\b(\d{4})\b` in group1 and capturing any other one or more characters that doesn't have four digits using this `((?!\b\d{4}\b).)+` regex and we do a conditional replace, where if first alternation is matched then group1 is not empty hence replace it with matched text and if group1 is empty meaning second regex matched, hence replace it using a comma instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "abc 23 [1981] ghj [5656]"
print(re.findall(r"\[(\d{4})\]", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['1981', '5656']
```